# Lights Flickering 100V neutral impulse

Tags: electrical

I had a new house built and have been going back and forth between electrician and electric company. All the lights in my house flicker (both can and fixture) and sometimes actually go out. I do not have any dimmers installed. I purchased the Powertronics Probe 100+ and started logging the issues on my pc.  I get up to 100v neutral impulse and 50v hot impulses all over the house. I found a recall on the SQD power panel and could hear arcing so the electrician replaced the bus assembly 2 days ago.  The flickering is not as intense as before but it's still happening and not as frequently but the voltage impulses never went away. Electric Co put a logger on the meter previously and said no issues found.  I connected the probe up to both of my neighbors and found they have the same voltage impulse readings as me. I am beginning to think it now may be the electric company. Has anyone ran into this and have any ideas on how to get resolved?

Comment: What are your voltages hot-neutral? Use a Kill-a-Watt to measure outlets all over your home.  Are there 2 groups of voltages, one above 120V and the other below?   Does turning on a hair dryer change the voltage at a particular outlet on a different circuit?  Does turning on a 240V load like an oven or dryer make the voltage stabilize?

Comment: Sounds like a pole transformer ("pole pig") arcing internally, starting to die, can do this. Eventually, he x'former will destroy itself with spectacular fireworks, so the cause should be evident.

Comment: All outlets are 123V with the exception of the ongoing sags.

Answer (score -1):

Not too sure about this, could be these impulses used to control offpeak tarriff load, if so then speak to your utility company about reduce the ripple control signal sent out from the substation?.